# How do I redirect one subdomain to another, when they both point to the exact same files?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that has two domains pointing to it, let's call them:

```
work.mysite.com
play.mysite.com
```

This is bad practice, so I want to choose `work.mysite.com` and make it the canonical URL, permanently redirecting `play.mysite.com` to it.

I'm in the root directory for these two domains, in a .htaccess file, banging my head against the cement floor and wishing I wasn't here. Here's what I am currently trying. Tell me how totally wrong I am, please?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?play\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)?$ http://work.mysite.com/$1 [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

That gets me a really pretty 500 Internal Server Error. How far off am I?

Answer (score 6):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !work.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://work.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

This will also remove the www from www.work.example.com

Not sure if the QSA is needed, but I think it will prevent play.example.com/?home from being redirecting to work.example.com/ instead of work.example.com/?home

Comment: No need for `QSA` -- its only required if you modify query string, otherwise it will be passed unchanged.

Comment: Use a slash in b/w ^(.*)  and $ in second line. Otherwise the new url will ends with // . For instance work.example.com//  ...

Modified:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !work.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://work.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

Comment: @Rameez in the `.htaccess` context the leading slash is removed. If you use the above code in the `server config` you need to add a slash, but you'd have to add it at the start, not at the end, like you did. So `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ ...`. Otherwise e.g. `example.com/index.html` will not match!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I was just trying to be too fancy. This seems to work fine:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^play.mysite.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://work.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.play.mysite.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://work.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jquery\.webcodehelpers\.com
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://uieiq.webcodehelpers.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I used this to redirect a subdomain to another subdomain.